# Dropdown List appears empty when using @parameter

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a dropdownlist work for me. A user can be in many 'Field1's, so I wanted the dropdown to show those Field1s. 
Currently what happens is I just get a blank list. Here is a sample of the code:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM table 
                                    WHERE (Field3= @Field3)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Field3" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

If I remove the select parameters and the WHERE clause the list of all DHBs appears - it just seems to have issues with @Field3.

Edit: I have tested the query in SQL Server and it works for me (by replacing @Field3 with a known value)

Any suggestions? I am very new to asp.net, and have next to nothing in the .cs file (besides some authorisation and such), so if people could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic.

Edit 2: It would probably help if I gave you the whole template:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Field1" SortExpression="Field2">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Field2") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Field1" DataValueField="Field1">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="Field1 FROM table 
                                    WHERE (Field3 = @Field3)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Field3" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're populating another control using Dropdownlist selectedValue as a parameter, that is dictated by your code. In this case
You're missing property in the controlParameter

```
<SelectParameters>
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Property="SelectedValue" Name="Field3" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

If you're trying to populate `DropDownList1` you're completely derailed. In this case you need to show up more markup code and details.

**Update**:    You cannot take the parameters value from the `DropDownList` control which you're populating. Either remove the parameter or use another control to provide the value

Comment: Sorry - I didn't realise I left out part of the dropdown code. I have posted the rest

Comment: You want to populate DropDownList1? Then you cannot take parameter value from the same control.

Comment: I see - so I would need to take the parameter value from somewhere else? I have a boundfield for UserName, but besides that I don't see where else I could get it from. Do I need to make a new control?

Comment: Ah - I know what my problem is. The controlID I want is a cell in the gridview this is part of.
Is there any way to access that?

Comment: @vegetas_angel what do you mean? You want to access a cell in the same row, if so use binding expression